# Nodemon is installed, but doesn't run server

Tags: node.js, nodemon

**Nodemon** was working fine to run server in the beginning. After I tried to downgrade the version of node, I didn't work. **node server/** works fine, but **nodemon server/** doesn't work.
I tried to install nodemon, but it's already there.

`$ npm i -g nodemon`
`C:\Users\shyld\.npm-global\nodemon -> C:\Users\shyld\.npm-global\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js`

nodemon@2.0.4
updated 1 package in 4.495s

But It doesn't show the version.

`$ nodemon -v`
 `C:\Users\shyld\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found`

When I try to run nodemon, it uses node's path. I think problem is here, but I couldn't find the solution yet.

`$ nodemon server/`

`C:\Users\shyld\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found`

Comment: after downgrade node do you reinstall nodemon

Comment: It sounds like your node installation is messed up somehow.

Comment: yes, I reinstalled it.

Comment: Try deleting `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm` and `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` and reinstalling your global npm modules. (Make backup first.)